# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion

I haven't seen it asked yet, but question #6 on the [7 Essential Metal Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) **What should our logo and site design look like?**

> This one is pretty straightforward. Solicit contributions, throw out
>   ideas, post preliminary (or finished) designs, and be supportive and
>   respectful of other people’s ideas and creativity.
>
> We have designers on staff who will actively help come up with site
>   designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as
>   exceptional, we are happy to use it.

Let's use this topic to discuss our design ideas. What do **you** want Moderators.SE to look like?

Comment: That blog post is obsolete. We've been [badgering Stack Exchange to get it updated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201776), but unfortunately, in vain. Site design will be made by a professional when the site graduates from beta (months or years from now) and this thread will have very little influence if any. [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674) is a good overview of how betas really work.

Comment: Not to mention that we're *far* from site graduation - public beta comes first. Site design won't be a relevant matter for the foreseeable future either way.

Comment: @Gilles 6 to 8 units of time, is now the average.

Comment: I don't think we're in a position to fully know what this site is going to become if / when it graduates to full status. I think it needs to find its feet and let it grow organically before we can know a suitable direction for the branding to take.

Answer (score 5):

I propose that we put this question in mothballs for a while; until the site is near graduation it won't be relevant, and it doesn't make sense to accumulate answers now when the scope -- and participants, for that matter -- could change significantly before then.

If an answer gets a net-positive score, Community will stop bumping this question.  I offer this answer for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There's been some discussion about this in the [What should our chat room's name be?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-should-our-chat-rooms-name-be) thread, but whereas people like the Ban Hammer idea for the chat room (and some for the logo), I think it sends the wrong message and we should consider something more neutral, and I like Jack Douglas' janitorial idea.

How about something like the "Cleaning in Progress" logos you get, a gender neutral stick figure with a broom/mop, like this from [Seton](http://www.seton.co.uk/caution-cleaning-progress-safety-warning-board.html):

[image: Cleaning in progress]

Comment: I don't want to project a janitorial image. This site is about community building. Moderation is just one aspect (and a poor choice of name, which we must not emphasize with matching imagery).

Comment: @Gilles, I agree. I'd prefer to project "community building"

Comment: What about a compromise: A'la coat of arms, crossed, a banhammer and a mop.